# Create a double value from two separate variables C#

Tags: c#, math, logic

I have two seperate variables x and y of Integer types

Lets say x = 123 and y = 456. I want to create a double using these two variables such that 
result = 123.456.

How do i get this?

Comment: Assume they are `int`, divide `y` with `1000.0` and add it to `x`?

Comment: what type is `x` and `y`?

Comment: store x +"."+y as string, and convert string to double

Comment: double Result = (double)X + (double)Y/1000; ?

Comment: this way >> double mydoule = Convert.ToDouble("123" + "." + "456");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static double Combine(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0) throw new NotSupportedException(); // need to specify
           // how it should behave when x or y is below 0
    if (y == 0) return x;

    var fractionMultipler = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(y)) + 1;
    var divider = Math.Pow(10, fractionMultipler);


    return x + (y / divider);
}
```

Sample:

```
 var z = Combine(30, 11123); // result 30.11123
```

Comment: Awesome...+1 for using pure mathematics

Comment: but why you want `x > 0`?

Comment: In my code -10 combined with 6 will output -9.4. Don't know if it is what the OP expects. Maybe it should be -10.6. Need to be specified :)

Comment: @Softwarehuset  and show code of your benchmark, because my tests  even for small ints is faster than yours.

Comment: @Softwarehuset in you benchmark for small ints and iterations the problem is that my code is called as method but your solution is inline. Make my code inline too and then test it :)

Comment: @Softwarehuset you should not delete your answer - it's working alternative ;)

Comment: @pwas :) i hate to see a solution which is less efficient at stack overflow. Therefore i have deleted it :) you made a perfect code for this problem.